# random image selector from a directory with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, image, random, background

im using jquery.min.

`function LoadImages()
    {`

i've tried to use jasper roos winkel jquery plugin to do that but its not necessarily fulfill my needs:

http://www.jasperrooswinkel.com/smooth-fullscreen-background-slideshow-in-jquery/

here is my problem:

i have a folder with thousands of images on my webserver. i want a dynamic background changer with jquery. which will select one image on every 5 seconds randomly from that folder and put it to the background. how can i do that?

waiting for your helps.

Comment: any code you wrote that will help us solve the problem?

Comment: what code do you have so far?

Comment: well i didn't actually. i've just tried to edit jasperroos background slideshop plugin but its too complex. i'm new in that stuff so i didn't understand how to modify it to folder basis :(

Comment: Unless you plan on manually updating a list of available images from that server folder I would suggest making an AJAX call to a PHP script which randomly chooses an image for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a small PHP script returning a random filename from your image directory

```
<?
    $files = glob('path-to-dir/*.*');
    $file = array_rand($files);
    echo $files[$file];
?>
```

and call that script with jquery AJAX :

```
function loadBackground() {
   $.ajax({
      url: 'getimage.php',
      success : function(filename) {
         $('body').css('background-image', 'url('+filename+')');
      }
   });
}
```

call it each 5 secs

```
setInterval(loadBackground, 5000);
```

---

When styling the background, use the `background`-selector instead of the `background-image` selector :

```
$('body').css('background', 'url('+filename+') no-repeat center center fixed');
```

Comment: thank you david! it totally worked! but one more thing. when i try to add no-repeat center fixed specs to the code that you wrote im getting error. probably because of me :)

$('body').css('background-image', 'url('+filename+') no-repeat center center fixed');

isnt that correct?

Comment: nope there is one problem left :) its not centering the image. for example i have 2000x1000 pixel image and it displays it like full dimensions. not centered to the browser. im using this on css:

body {
overflow-y: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
overflow-y: scroll;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}

Comment: and is there any possible way to make smooth transition between images?

Comment: Hey, I think the two above new questions is better off as a new question. It is a completely different area.

Comment: yep i have fixed the centering problem by adding new lines to $('body'.css area. but the second one :) smooth transition.. :/

Comment: sry, not so familiar with "fancy" styling, so try it out as a new question. regards,